# Неправильно работают рикошеты

Tags: c#, unity3d

`Rigidbody2D` стоит и у `Bullet`, и у `Stone`.
Коллайдеры тоже.
Рикошеты работают странно под разными углами, а иногда и вовсе влетают внутрь объекта и вылетают с обратной стороны.

> Немного фото для понимания

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (true) // это временно
    {
        bullet1.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime); // перемещение bullet вперед
    }
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        live1--; // снятие одного очка за рикошет
        Vector3 v = Vector3.Reflect(transform.right, col.contacts[0].normal);
        float rot = - Mathf.Atan2(v.z, v.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rot);
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте поставить для rigidbody пуль collision detection - continous dynamic

Comment: Уже стоит, на камне точно так же

Comment: попробуйте для отладки нарисовать нормаль, по которой вы считаете рикошеты...

Comment: попробуйте двигать пулю не транслейтом, а придавая ей скорость и направление, физический движок плохо переносит прямое изменение transform.position

Comment: и кстати не потребуется считать рикошет, физика юнити сделает это за Вас

Comment: у меня без рикошета пуля упирается в камень и продолжает ехать в таком же направлении

Comment: Вы прочиталимое сообщение про скорость,  силу и transform.position?)

Comment: А все потому кто-то когда-то с упорством всем доказывал, что transform.position можно менять и это **никак не повлияет** на физический движок, поразительно, сколько проблем это уже создало и сколько еще их создаст.